# What is the maximum data transfer speed using SPI interface on Arduino?

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, spi, raspberry-pi-pico, arduino-nano

What is the maximum data transfer speed using SPI interface on Arduino?

I have an Arduino Nano and I want to transfer data between it and a Raspberry Pico. I use SPI interface, and I want to know, what is the data speed limit (in bit per second).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look into the Atmega328p datasheet, then there is:

- F_OSC/2 in Master mode (with double speed SPI bit set), otherwise F_OSC/4
- As a slave at best F_OSC/4

Comment: So, when FOSC of Arduino is 16 MHz, than it's 4 MHz, it is in bit per second 4 Mbit per sec, is it?

Comment: Yes, but you'll probably reach software bottleneck at this speed.